# My graph's y axis is mixed, what happened?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
x=[['a', 30, 9, 8, 12],
 ['b', 26, 6, 6, 4],
 ['c', 23, 9, 14, 16],
 ['d', 16, 3, 1, 1],
 ['e', 12, 0, 0, 0]]
```

My data looks like this.

```
for i in x:
    plt.plot(i[1:], label=i[0])

plt.show()
```

When I run this code, this shows:

[image]

I want to sort y axis, how can I do that?

Comment: The phenomenon in the image in question occurs when the value is a string. I ran your code and it correctly aligns the y-axis ticks from 0 to 30. Check the type of data and the version of `matplotlib` you are using to make sure it is not out of date.

Comment: I fixed it using .astype(int) following up r-beginners's advice.